# Is it OK to use an Ubuntu kernel for Linux Mint?

Tags: kernel, mint

My question is simple.

Is it OK to use an Ubuntu kernel for Linux Mint? My Linux Kernel for Ubuntu is version 4.4.0-31. However, I would like to use it for Linux Mint 19 Tara because it has all the modules I need (yes, it all sounds weird).

### Are the configurations different or not?

Does Linux Mint have a different kernel configuration, despite being built (or at least based on) Ubuntu? Would it be completely safe to use an Ubuntu kernel? Is there anything deprecated or not?

### Would it affect my usage of Linux Mint?

Will it do anything at all if I use it? For example, might I end up with a huge battery drain, random crashes and errors, performance issues etc? Is it dangerous?

Comment: This isn't really a question about Ubuntu, and so it's off topic. The Unix & Linux Stack Exchange would be the better place to ask this.

Comment: That's a great question to ask Mint support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run diff on the two kernel configuration files to gain insight into the differences. There is also a cool script in the kernel source tree (at least the git version), scripts/diffconfig, that makes nicely formatted results. Example:

```
doug@s15:~/temp-k-git/linux$ scripts/diffconfig .config-4.20-rc1-doug .config-4.20-rc3-doug
 ADXL372_I2C n -> m
 ADXL372_SPI n -> m
 ASYMMETRIC_TPM_KEY_SUBTYPE n -> m
 ....[snip]...
 STM_PROTO_SYS_T n -> m
 VL53L0X_I2C n -> m
+ADXL372 m
+I2C_NVIDIA_GPU m
+NET_DSA_TAG_GSWIP y
+SND_SOC_HDAC_HDA m
+SND_SOC_PCM3060 m
+TPM_KEY_PARSER m
+UCSI_CCG m
```

You should be able to find your kernel configuration files on /boot.

Yes, you should be able to run kernels from other distributions on each other. I do it often. It shouldn't be dangerous, but as for battery or performance, try it and see.

Your other, and perhaps better, option is to compile your linux mint kernel yourself, changing the kernel configuration to include those modules that you require but for whatever reason are set to "no".

Comment: Thank you so much. To be quite honest, I think that's good enough for me. <3